# Vue 3 Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Ref<string>'

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I have this code which works perfectly fine on my localhost. But Typescript throws me an error  **Type 'string' is not assignable to type Ref<string>.**

```
let placeholderTitle = ref<string>('')


function beforeDragStart() {
    placeholderTitle = ''
    ....
}
```

Can somedy tell me please what is the problem with this code.

Secondly why this composition api allowes me to asign value straight to the placeholderTitle and placeholdertitle.value = throws me an error?

Comment: Being a `Ref`, placeholderTitle has to be a constant (`const` instead of `let`).

Comment: Then it throws me an error that I try to asign value to constant variable.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Could you check now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a Ref, `placeholderTitle` has to be a **constant** (`const` instead of `let`).

Using `let` allows you to change the content of `placeholderTitle`, but then Typescript throws legitimately a type error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type Ref<string>`.

To change the content of a Ref, you have to change its inner `.value`:

```
function beforeDragStart() {
    placeholderTitle.value = ''
    ....
}
```

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but as I said if I use const it throws me an error that I try to asign value to the const variable.

Comment: But did you really assign using `.value`? The error should really not appear in that case

Comment: Sorry there was another line which assign value directly to placeholderTitle

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**
If you want to change the value of a `Ref` object, you have to assign it to its `.value` property.

```js
function beforeDragStart() {
    placeholderTitle.value = ''
}
```

From the docs:

> ref() takes an inner value and returns a reactive and mutable ref object, which has a single property .value that points to the inner value.

Notice that within the `<template>` you do not need to use `.value` since Vue conveniently unwrapps it for you.

**Regarding the use of let**

While using `let` to declare a `Ref` works, I recommend using a `const` to ensure the reference remains immutable (and only it's reactive `.value` property changes which will be reflected in your UI) and to promote clearer, more maintainable code.